# Restrict values in spark dataframe to only specified values

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My spark dataframe as below

```
+-----+------+-----------+
|col_1| col_2|      col_3|
+-----+------+-----------+
|  abc|   123|    Allowed|
|dasdj|  null|Not-Allowed|
|  dce|   786|      wrong|
| null| 23456|Not-Allowed|
|  def|682364|       temp|
|  bcr|   786|Not-Allowed|
+-----+------+-----------+
```

my requirement is to create a new column and capture all null values in `col_1` and `col_2` and capture `col_3` value if it is not  "Allowed" or "Not-Allowed" and replace the `col_3` invalid values with the default value("Not-Allowed")

Issue column contains the concatenated output of `col_1`,`col_2`,`col_3` if `col_1` or `col_2` is null or `col_3` is anything other than Allowed and Not-Allowed.

once after the concatenation, I want to update `col_3` with the default value which is "Not-Allowed".

My expected output:

```
+-----+------+-----------+------------------+
|col_1| col_2|      col_3|             issue|
+-----+------+-----------+------------------+
|  abc|   123|    Allowed|              null|
|dasdj|  null|Not-Allowed|dasdj,,Not-Allowed|
|  dce|   786|Not-Allowed|     dce,786,wrong|
| null| 23456|Not-Allowed|,23456,Not-Allowed|
|  def|682364|Not-Allowed|   def,682364,temp|
|  bcr|   786|Not-Allowed|              null|
+-----+------+-----------+------------------+
```

Would be grateful if any one can suggest me a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `when` function to check whether `col_1` or `col_2` are null or `col_3` different from values Allowed/Not-Allowed, then conacat the columns :

```
val df1 = df.withColumn(
    "issue",
    when(
      $"col_1".isNull || $"col_2".isNull || !$"col_3".isin("Allowed", "Not-Allowed"),
      concat_ws(
        ",",
        coalesce($"col_1", lit("")),
        coalesce($"col_2", lit("")),
        $"col_3"
      )
    )
  ).withColumn(
    "col_3",
    when(!$"col_3".isin("Allowed", "Not-Allowed"), "Not-Allowed").otherwise($"col_3")
  )


df1.show
//+-----+------+-----------+------------------+
//|col_1| col_2|      col_3|             issue|
//+-----+------+-----------+------------------+
//|  abc|   123|    Allowed|              null|
//|dasdj|  null|Not-Allowed|dasdj,,Not-Allowed|
//|  dce|   786|Not-Allowed|     dce,786,wrong|
//| null| 23456|Not-Allowed|,23456,Not-Allowed|
//|  def|682364|Not-Allowed|   def,682364,temp|
//|  bcr|   786|Not-Allowed|              null|
//+-----+------+-----------+------------------+
```

To update column `col_3` with the default value `Not-Allowed`, you use the same logic with `when` function.